# Closing second child form when opened by 1st child in parent window

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing following code in parent form to open only 1 child form at a time and its working fine when I open `child form` from `parent form`

```
public void OpenForm(Form toOpen)
            {
                foreach (Form child in MdiChildren)
                    child.Close();

                toOpen.MdiParent = this;
                toOpen.Show();
            } 
private void btnExam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenForm(new ChooseExam(LoginName));            
        }
```

but when I open `2nd child form` from `1st child form` ,that time in my `parent window` these both child forms appear at same time ,now how can i close `first child form` when opening `2nd child form` through it ,and in back button of 2nd form how can i see 1st child form back
I tried same above code in child form with this line of code `toOpen.MdiParent = this.ParentForm ;` but still I can see both child forms , how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not close your `first child form` because you'll also close your `second child form`. If you close parent form you are closing child form. What you can do is to hide it:

```
firstChildForm.Hide();
```

and when you want to see it:

```
firstChildForm.Show();
```